# why I got memory still reachable when it's not reachable

Tags: c, memory-leaks

this is the struct of list:

```
struct link {
    char name[20]; 
    list* next;
};
```

this is the function that valgrind say that the memory is still reachable.

```
list* make_new_link(char* name) {
    list* new_link = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    new_link->name = name;
    new_link->next = NULL;

    return new_link;

}
```

at the end of the code I freed the list like so:
NOTE: list* lst is the pointer of the list

```
void free_list(list* lst) {
    list* temp = NULL;

    while(lst->next != NULL) {
        temp = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

so why I still get an memory problem?

Comment: What about `name`? What manages the lifetime of it?

Comment: Please produce a [mre]

Comment: Whatever pointer you give to the `free_list()`, after finishing, the memory it refers to has been freed but the pointer still points to it. That is what valgrind wants to tell you. Please provide a [mre] to go into details.

Answer (score 0):

You never clean up the first element because of `while(lst->next != NULL)`. Fix it like this:

```
void free_list(list* lst) {
    list* temp = NULL;

    while(lst != NULL) {
        temp = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```